# Splitting a number into factors of 100 with remainder

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm sure this has been answered else where, but for the life of me, I cannot find it. What I'm trying to do is, for a given n, create an array of factors of 100 for said number, including the remainder.

So for example: n = 535

Would return:

array = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 35]

I've been trying to use:

```
var mindnumbing = Array.apply(null,     
Array((N/100))).map(Number.prototype.valueOf,100);
```

But can't figure out how to carry the remainder (and any non-factor of 100 tosses an error, as expected).

Comment: 35 = 535 modulo 100.

Comment: The word "factor" is really not the word you want to be using here. Specifically, `100` is not a factor of `535`.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to figure out the math word, but couldn't think of it. Multiple? Sorry, writer first, math second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// create an array and fill it with 100-s "(N/100) rounded down" times:
var array = Array(Math.floor(N / 100)).fill(100);

// and add the "remainder of N/100", which is written as: N%100:
array.push(N%100);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: `Array(Math.floor(number / 100)).fill(100)` to save a loop

Comment: Now it's not obvious what is `N` and if the `0` as reminder must be appended.

Comment: Thanks! That got it.

So if you please, can you explain the logic? What's generating the 35?

This: array.push(N%100) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
function splitHundreds(number) {
  if( number < 100 ) return [number];
  else {
    var array = [];
    while( number >= 100 ) {
      array.push(100);
      number -= 100;
    }
    if( number > 0 ) array.push(number);
    return array;
  }
}
```

It doesn't use modulo (the `%` operator), but seems to work for values I put into it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see the need to use d3, you could just do this:

```
function getHundreds(n) {
        var ary = [];
    while(n>=100) {
        ary.push(100);
        n-=100;
    }
    if(n>0) ary.push(n);
    return ary;
}
```

Comment: `ary.push(n%100);` --- you don't need `% 100` here, the number is already less than 100. Another thing - it should be a `>= 100` check.

Comment: If n <100 it would skip the while loop. you want to return the single number, not an empty array. Edit: Never mind, see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify your code as little as possible, but I'd probably use a while-loop, just for better readability.

```
var mindnumbing = Array.apply(null,     
Array((Math.floor(N/100)))).map(Number.prototype.valueOf,100);
var mod=N%100;
if(mod>0){
    mindnumbing.push(mod);
}
console.log(mindnumbing);
```